Cannot complete login due to an incorrect user name or password
I have a vCenter version 6.0.0.3 which was turned off for some reason. When I powered it back on, its network settings were deleted! And I couldn't log in with the vCenter root password; it showed an incorrect password error. Using Ubuntu live, I changed the root password, reconfigured the network and DNS settings, and regained access to the vCenter machine.
However, when I tried to log in to the vCenter using the vSphere client, I encountered the incorrect username or password error with both the local administrator@vsphere.local user and the domain users.
I activated SSH and shell on the vCenter (version 6.0.0.3), logged in via SSH, and used the following command to generate a new password for the administrator@vsphere.local user:
/usr/lib/vmware-vmdir/bin/vdcadmintool

But even with this new password, I still got the same error.
Steps I have taken:

Restarted the vCenter once, but the issue persisted.
Restarted all services within the vCenter from the shell.
Manually synchronized the vCenter time exactly with the ESXi host time.

Despite these efforts, the incorrect username or password error persists.
